# Clip/Intersect tool stopped working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, intersect, error-000210, warning-000117

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

I have been using the Clip tool to cut out the amount of a given habitat type found within individual buffers around individual samples. After successfully executing this command many times and receiving outputs, the Clip tool suddenly started to produce an error message:

> Error000210: Cannot create output

despite my having made zero changes between successful/unsuccessful executions of the command.

I then switched to the Intersect tool which worked fine for a while, until it too started to produce a warning message:

> Warning000117: Warning empty output generated

again without my having made any changes.

I have tried to "Check/Repair Geometry", as well as recreating/reloading my shapefiles, but to no avail. Also, the errors now occur on all samples, including the ones that originally worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] the question to provide more details on "stopped working" and "fails", preferably with the exact Geoprocessing Results inputs and results logs.

Comment: Spatial reference parameters can have a huge say in topology errors.  The SR for a shapefile merges the coordinate reference from the .prj with something which should be appropriate for the geometry processing, but you can do a better job if you create a file geodatabase, define a feature dataset with the desired tolerances, copy the shapefiles into the FDS, drag them back out again, and then do the processing in file geodatabase. There's also Background Geoprocessing as a complication, which you should disable when having issues.

Comment: If you have access to a Spatial Analyst license, it may be easier to do this in a raster format using the "Focal Statistics" tool. Then either "Extract Values to Points" or "Zonal Statistics" (in the case of polygon samples) the results to your samples.  This avoids issues that may arise if your sample buffers overlap, as well.